# Read Stream not doing firing / catching errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary

I am trying to create a read stream to use Cloudinary's upload stream function, I am also using resumable.js to chunk the initial file, while the create read stream is working perfectly fine (as the whole file gets written perfectly fine.) the read stream / cloudinary upload function seems to not even be firing and failing silently.

```
router.post("/upload", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("the params are.. ", req.body);

  resumable.post(req, function(
    status,
    filename,
    original_filename,
    identifier
  ) {
    if (status === "done") {
      let timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString();
  //stich the chunks

  var s = fs.createWriteStream(timestamp + filename);
  resumable.write(identifier, s);

  var upload_stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
    { tags: "basic_sample" },
    function(err, image) {
      console.log();
      console.log("** Stream Upload");
      if (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
      console.log("* Same image, uploaded via stream");
      console.log("* " + image.public_id);
      console.log("* " + image.url);
      waitForAllUploads(timestamp + filename, err, image);
    }
  );

    fs.createReadStream(timestamp + filename)
    .pipe(upload_stream)
    .on("error", err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  s.on("finish", function() {
    // Stream upload
    console.log("ive finished...");
    // delete chunks
    setTimeout(() => {
      resumable.clean(identifier);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
res.send(status);
  });
});
```

Here are the resources to what I am using:

https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/samples/basic/basic.js

https://github.com/mrawdon/resumable-node

Answer (score 1):

fs.createReadStream(timestamp + filename) accepts the file path but looks like you are passing the timestamp as well. Also, waitForAllUploads is not defined. You can try the following code just using Node and Cloudinary to test it out.

```
var upload_stream= cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream({tags: 'basic_sample'},function(err,image) {
  console.log("** Stream Upload");
  if (err){ console.warn(err);}
  console.log("* "+image.url)
});
var file_reader = fs.createReadStream('<file path>').pipe(upload_stream);
```

Comment: This works fine actually! However, I cannot access the console logs inside the callback... I never see   console.log("* "+image.url) Even though I've logged into my Cloudinary account and have seen the image being uploaded perfectly